# Splitting an object into two

Tags: physics, procedural-destruction

I'm using Farseer physics engine.

I have a simple rectangle body and would like it to split into two pieces given a starting coordinate (where the bullet enters the object) and ending coordinate (where it exits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common technique for creating cutaways or cross-sections is to use an arbitrary clipping plane to exclude a part of the body. By cloning the body and clipping an opposite part of the body you end up with two pieces of something that appears to have been sliced in two.

You would then have to use the stencil buffer to 'fill in' the clip edges, and create new physics bodies for the two new bodies.

http://glbook.gamedev.net/moglgp/advclip.asp

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the stencil buffer. Is there a way of doing it in Silverlight?

Comment: You could try replacing the original mesh with two new meshes. Using the points of intersection of the cut, and using those points as the new vertices for the new meshes.

Comment: I guess this will be the best way to do it. Thanks.